# When I try to recreate an Activity the app crashes

Tags: java, android

I'm coding an app that has two Activity's. The first one sets content view to an .xml. In the .xml when a button is clicked it calls another activity and sets the view again.

Up to this part, it works perfectly. But when the app reaches a certain point it calls a method in the first activity that should `recreate()`. But the `recreate()` crashes my app.

Find my two activities below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private GameActivity gameAc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startGame(View v) {



    gameAc = new GameActivity();//this line calls the second activity


}



public void setViewActivity(){

    recreate(); // this is the line that crashes the app

}

}
```

Now this is my second activity

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

//declare class Gamedraw
private GameDraw gameDraw;

//too hold screen dimensions
Point size = new Point();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //get phone dimensions
    Display display = getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay();

    display.getSize(size);



    //initialse class
    gameDraw = new GameDraw(this, size);



    //set view to gamedraw
    setContentView(gameDraw);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gameDraw.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gameDraw.pause();
}
}
```

In the fist activity. the `recreate()` crashes the app.

Not entirely sure if this is what you meant by a stacktrace. If it's not please let me know.

~

```
2019-10-14 12:16:32.987 18795-18795/? I/roid.runningma: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-10-14 12:16:33.303 18795-18795/? W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:2662): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=106 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:33.309 18795-18795/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2019-10-14 12:16:33.467 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.android.runningman is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
2019-10-14 12:16:33.469 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
2019-10-14 12:16:34.472 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: Debugger has connected
2019-10-14 12:16:34.473 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:34.674 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:34.876 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) identical 1 line
2019-10-14 12:16:35.077 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:35.278 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:35.479 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:35.680 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:35.881 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:36.081 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) identical 1 line
2019-10-14 12:16:36.282 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
2019-10-14 12:16:36.483 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/System.out: debugger has settled (1301)
2019-10-14 12:16:37.219 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/PackageManager: return text:  RunningManfor package: com.example.android.runningman
2019-10-14 12:16:37.272 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-10-14 12:16:37.275 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@fc013c8
2019-10-14 12:16:37.307 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2663): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.310 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.310 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2664): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.315 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.317 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2665): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.319 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.320 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2666): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.323 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.323 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2667): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.327 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.327 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2668): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.331 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.333 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2669): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.336 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.337 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2670): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.340 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.340 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/roid.runningman: type=1400 audit(0.0:2671): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:37.344 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.404 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) identical 14 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:37.409 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.416 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.578 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) identical 34 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:37.581 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels fEnTdshp 0 fISOSpeedRatings -1!
2019-10-14 12:16:37.652 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/PhoneWindow: isNeedChangeNaviBarColor taskInfo: [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@f490221] size: 1
2019-10-14 12:16:37.655 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/PhoneWindow: isAPPNeedChange pkgName: com.example.android.runningman needKeep: false
2019-10-14 12:16:37.655 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/PhoneWindow: isNeedChangeNaviBarColor false
2019-10-14 12:16:37.656 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout mNavigationBarColor: ff000000
2019-10-14 12:16:37.657 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/PhoneWindow: generateLayout isLightNavi false, Visibility: 0
2019-10-14 12:16:38.124 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2019-10-14 12:16:38.338 18795-18828/com.example.android.runningman I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-14 12:16:38.338 18795-18828/com.example.android.runningman I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-14 12:16:38.339 18795-18828/com.example.android.runningman I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-14 12:16:38.339 18795-18828/com.example.android.runningman D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-10-14 12:16:38.374 18795-18828/com.example.android.runningman D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2019-10-14 12:16:38.467 18795-18828/com.example.android.runningman E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2019-10-14 12:16:38.463 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:2723): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7489 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c200,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2019-10-14 12:16:39.449 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:39.512 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:39.569 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:39.626 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:39.682 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:39.905 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 6 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:39.931 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:39.959 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:40.107 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 7 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:40.120 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:40.134 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:40.984 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 51 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:41.000 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.017 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.036 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.053 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.068 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.087 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.103 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.121 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.136 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.388 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 15 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:41.405 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.422 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.791 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 22 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:41.808 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:41.825 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:42.010 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 11 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:42.027 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:42.045 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:42.346 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 18 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:42.363 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:42.383 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.221 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 50 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:43.238 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.254 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-10-14 12:16:43.254 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-10-14 12:16:43.255 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.271 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.292 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.308 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.327 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.327 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Looper android.app.ActivityThread.getLooper()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.recreate(Activity.java:5583)
        at com.example.android.runningman.MainActivity.setViewActivity(MainActivity.java:60)
        at com.example.android.runningman.GameDraw.onTouchEvent(GameDraw.java:389)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1839)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:399)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12789)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5279)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5073)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7336)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7305)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7262)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7453)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
2019-10-14 12:16:43.327 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-10-14 12:16:43.339 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas

    --------- beginning of crash
2019-10-14 12:16:43.368 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.runningman, PID: 18795
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Looper android.app.ActivityThread.getLooper()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.recreate(Activity.java:5583)
        at com.example.android.runningman.MainActivity.setViewActivity(MainActivity.java:60)
        at com.example.android.runningman.GameDraw.onTouchEvent(GameDraw.java:389)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12545)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2684)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1839)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:399)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12789)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5279)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5073)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4639)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7336)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7305)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7262)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7453)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
2019-10-14 12:16:43.390 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman I/chatty: uid=10200(com.example.android.runningman) Thread-2 identical 3 lines
2019-10-14 12:16:43.409 18795-18827/com.example.android.runningman D/Surface: lockCanvas
2019-10-14 12:16:43.426 18795-18795/com.example.android.runningman I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18795 SIG: 9
```

~~

This is the code that calls setViewActivity();
The code is in my GameDraw class (the one that gets called in the second activity. This class handles screen user inputs and draws the game.

```
 public class GameDraw extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

 private MainActivity MAobject;

  public GameDraw(Context context, Point size) {
 //this handles all drawing to screen
 }


  @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

            if (death == false) {

                if (firstRun) {
                    firstRun = false;
                    gravity = true;
                    Log.e("viewtrace", "test");

                } else {
                    jumping = true;

                }
            }
            else{
                Log.e("viewtrace", "1");
                MAobject.setViewActivity();

            }

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Added the manifest that calls the first activity(ActivityMain).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.runningman">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: where do you call `setViewActivity()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity classes should not be instantiated directly (i.e. no `new YourActivity()`). They are created and destroyed by the system. To start a new activity you create an `Intent` and then call the `startActivity()` method of the `Context` class.

In your case, to start the `GameActivity` you would call something like

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
```

in your `startGame()` method.

For the updated question you also need to replace the call to `setViewActivity()` with

```
getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

You can find more information in the Android developer guides, e.g. [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#tba)

Since you updated your question another problem becomes apparent:
In Android you need to declare all Activities in your manifest. Your manifest contains only the MainActivity, so the GameActivity cannot be launched. To fix this problem you need to add the following declaration to the manifest file (between the `application` tags):

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".GameActivity"
    android:label="Some name for your Activity" />
```

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested and it's still crashing.

Comment: Ok, since you've updated the question my solution alone won't help. Where do you get the `MainActivity` object `MAobject` from? Normally you shouldn't have a reference to another activity. And in addition, why do you call `recreate()` in the first place? What would you like to happen when you call it? If you want to go back to the `MainActivity` you should also use `startActivity()` instead of calling `recreate()`

Comment: The reason I created the MAobject is because it won't let me recreate() from a static context. So if I just call the class.method it gives me errors. I left out a line: MAobject = new MainActivity(); where I declare the object. The reason I was using recreate is because I want to start the app from the beginning.

Comment: I'm assuming with the updated answer, I must put        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)); line inside the GameDraw class (where the setViewActivity() was originally called. When I do that it gives me error cannot resolve method. So my guess is that it has to be called from within an class that extends activity.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that this is in the view class. There you must replace `this` with `getContext()`. Then it should hopefully work. I've changed in the answer.

Comment: The problem seems to be that startActivity() needs to be called from a class that extends Activity. Where I used to call setViewActivity() is not in a class that extends Activity.

Comment: `startActivity()` is a function of the `Context` class from which the activity inherits. So if you call it like `getContext().startActivity(...)` it should work. Again, sorry that I missed this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Tried it the way you said, and it still doesn't work. I've added my Manifest that calls the first activity(the one I'm trying to restart). Just incase the problem is there.

Comment: I would like to thank and apologize to everyone that helped me. Android studio had some bug where it wouldn't update my code when I made changes. So no matter what I added it always crashed at the same place. I performed a rebuild and it now works. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where you called ? `setViewActivity();`

Try this for call other Activity

> ```
>      public void startGame(View v) 
>      {
>          startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
>      }
> ```